# Изменение и сохранение значений в Activity из DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Здравствуйте! Я использую DialogFragment со своей разметкой для вывода диалога в котором есть 4 пункта, (изменение размера текста, изменение цвета текста и тд.), я реализовал слушателя на список, и по нажатию на пункт открывается диалог алерт, в котором есть значения. Меня интересует следующее: Каким образом мне изменить из DialogFragment'a значения у TextView в главной активити? Я сделал так,

```
((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.head)).setTextSize(50);
```

Размер текста меняется, но я не могу сохранить выбранные значения, и при повторном открытии программы размер шрифта становится опять стандартным. Привожу код DialogFragment'a.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_dialog, container, false);

    getDialog().setTitle("Настройки");

  final List<SettingsVariable> settingsVar = new ArrayList<>();
    settingsVar.add(new SettingsVariable(22, R.color.silver, R.color.white, R.raw.times_new_roman));
    settingsVar.add(new SettingsVariable(32, R.color.white, R.color.white, R.raw.kabaret_simp));
    settingsVar.add(new SettingsVariable(42, R.color.black, R.color.black, R.raw.asylbek_mereke));

  mHead = ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.head));


  List<SettingDialogItems> dialogItems = new ArrayList<>();
    dialogItems.add(new SettingDialogItems("Размер текста", "Выберите размер текста", R.drawable.ic_action_text_size));
    dialogItems.add(new SettingDialogItems("Цвет текста", "Выберите цвет текста", R.drawable.ic_action_text_color));
    dialogItems.add(new SettingDialogItems("Цвет фона", "Выберите цвет фона", R.drawable.ic_action_background_color));
    dialogItems.add(new SettingDialogItems("ِШрифт", "Выберите шрифт", R.drawable.ic_action_style_font));

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>(
            dialogItems.size());

    Map<String, Object> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < dialogItems.size(); i++) {
        m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(mItem, dialogItems.get(i).getmItemName());
        m.put(mItem2, dialogItems.get(i).getmItemDescriptions());
        m.put(mImg, dialogItems.get(i).getmItemImage());
        data.add(m);
    }

    String[] from = {mItem, mItem2, mImg};
    int[] to = {R.id.txt_item_settings, R.id.txt_item_description, R.id.img_item_settings};

    SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(myView.getContext(), data, R.layout.item_settings,
            from, to);


  ListView list_settings = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.list_settings);
  list_settings.setAdapter(sAdapter);

  list_settings.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alt_bld.setTitle("Выберите размер шрифта")
                        .setItems(R.array.text_size, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog_one, int id) {
                                      mHead.setTextSize(settingsVar.get(id).getText_size());
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });
                AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_text_size);
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы значения сохранялись между запусками приложения, их надо записывать в постоянное хранилище, например `SharedPreferences`. В активити при старте читать эти значения и применять к виджетам. В диалоге писать в преференсы новые значения при изменении

Answer (score 2):

В диалоговом окне, когда будете менять значения `textView` в `Activity`, передаете параметры методу `save()`, тем самым вы сохраните ваши данные в `SharedPreferences`.

```
    public static void save(Context context, int textSize, int textColor, int bgColor, int font) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("textSize", textSize);
        editor.putInt("textColor", textColor);
        editor.putInt("bgColor", bgColor);
        editor.putInt("font", font);

        editor.apply();
    }
```

А при запуске Вашего `Activity` проверяете метод `load()` на `NULL`, и если нет, то получаете данные по порядку и зададите значения к вашим `TextView`.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> load(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        arrayList.add(sharedPreferences.getInt("textSize", 0));
        arrayList.add(sharedPreferences.getInt("textColor", 0));
        arrayList.add(sharedPreferences.getInt("bgColor", 0));
        arrayList.add(sharedPreferences.getInt("font", 0));

        return arrayList;
    }
```

Comment: не могли бы вы разъяснить более подробнее? Я обновил код, именно таким образом я хочу передавать значения в `textview`, но я не могу понять, каким образом передать эти значения в `save`. После того как значения передаются в `save`, `save` нужно прописать в `onStop` а `load` в `onCreate`?

Comment: Вообще на сколько такая реализация соответствует тому "как должно быть"? Правильно ли я понял методы работы диалоговых окон, или я в силу не знания усложнил задачу?

Comment: Да, можно и в `onStop()` или же при нажатии на кнопку `OK` в диалоговом окне отправлять ваши данные в параметры метода `save()`. Да, правильно в MainActivity в `onCreate()` вызываете метод `load()` и вставляете в `TextView` из `ArrayList` по этому порядку

Comment: Можете описать пример, каким образом отправить данные в метод ` save`? Я просто уже несколько дней все никак не могу сохранить эти значения, попробовал по разному через `sharedpreferens`, но не смог никак.

Comment: `save(R.drawable.ic_action_text_size, R.drawable.ic_action_text_color, R.drawable.ic_action_background_color, R.drawable.ic_action_style_font);`

Comment: не получается, я значения беру из settingVar.

Comment: И даже поянтия не имею load как вызвать

Comment: Извиняюсь что такой дуб

Comment: Нет, все нормально, просто у меня тоже тут проблемы, не успеваю)